# Lifetime compiler error on operation returning Box<Future>

Tags: rust, future, associated-types

I was experimenting with asynchronous operations using the `futures` with `tokio` crate and had no problems. Now I'm implementing a storage that loads up data asynchronously and then performs some transformations, but my interface seem to have some lifetime problem which I fail to understand.

This is a reduced test code showing the same symptoms; the real function bodies perform more reasonable actions than always returning errors:

```
extern crate futures; // v0.1 (old)

use futures::prelude::*;
use futures::future;

pub enum MyError {
    SomeError,
}

pub trait KeyValueStore {
    type ValueType;

    fn load(&self, key: String) -> Box<Future<Item = Vec<u8>, Error = MyError>>;
    fn deserialize(&self, serialized_obj: Vec<u8>) -> Result<Self::ValueType, MyError>;

    fn resolve(&self, key: String) -> Box<Future<Item = Self::ValueType, Error = MyError>>;
}

pub struct Storage<Obj> {
    _unused: std::marker::PhantomData<Obj>,
}

impl<Obj: 'static> KeyValueStore for Storage<Obj> {
    type ValueType = Obj;

    fn deserialize(&self, serialized_obj: Vec<u8>) -> Result<Self::ValueType, MyError> {
        Err(MyError::SomeError)
    }

    fn load(&self, key: String) -> Box<Future<Item = Vec<u8>, Error = MyError>> {
        Box::new(future::err(MyError::SomeError))
    }

    fn resolve(&self, key: String) -> Box<Future<Item = Self::ValueType, Error = MyError>> {
        let result = self.load(key).and_then(|bytes| self.deserialize(bytes));
        Box::new(result)
    }
}
```

The compiler rejects this sample code with the following lifetime problem:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:36:9
   |
36 |         Box::new(result)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 34:5...
  --> src/main.rs:34:5
   |
34 | /     fn resolve(&self, key: String) -> Box<Future<Item = Self::ValueType, Error = MyError>> {
35 | |         let result = self.load(key).and_then(|bytes| self.deserialize(bytes));
36 | |         Box::new(result)
37 | |     }
   | |_____^
note: ...so that the type `futures::AndThen<std::boxed::Box<futures::Future<Error=MyError, Item=std::vec::Vec<u8>>>, std::result::Result<Obj, MyError>, [closure@src/main.rs:35:46: 35:77 self:&&Storage<Obj>]>` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> src/main.rs:36:9
   |
36 |         Box::new(result)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that expression is assignable (expected std::boxed::Box<futures::Future<Error=MyError, Item=Obj> + 'static>, found std::boxed::Box<futures::Future<Error=MyError, Item=Obj>>)
  --> src/main.rs:36:9
   |
36 |         Box::new(result)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Previous code I have written with `hyper` or `tokio-postgres` seemingly had the same logic but never produced such errors. I can't even see where the lifetime could go wrong here without references. My gut feeling says it's somehow related to the generic `Obj` parameter, the static lifetime restriction doesn't feel right.

What circumstances cause the compile error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `self` in `self.deserialize` needs the lifetime from the `&self` parameter to `resolve`; the result cannot be boxed as `Box<Future<..>>`, which requires a `'static` lifetime for the boxed `Future`.

You could override the lifetime requirement for the boxed future with `Box<Future<..> + 'a>` (where `'a` is the lifetime of the `self` parameter; you'd need to change the `resolve` signature in the trait and in the implementation); but there is not much you can do with the result, as the usual `Future`-based event loops will require a `'static` lifetime for the `Future`s they have to run.

Instead you can solve this by making `deserialize` a "static method", i.e. removing the `&self` argument and calling it through `Self::deserialize` instead.

The default lifetime requirement (in this case `'static`) when using traits as types is documented in [Trait objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types.html#trait-objects) in the reference.

Comment: You're right, I somewhat overlooked the self lifetime. I also had this idea, but my original context was much more complex and probably still had some error left. I think the problematic thing is that in the compiler messages nothing refers to self as the cause of this error, so you can only guess where the problem is.
Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: "cannot be boxed"? I know nothing about tokio, but shouldn't `Box<'a + Future<...>>` work?

Comment: You're probably right, although a lifetime restricted future won't be of much use afaik. I'll try to have a look again.